# Calculate the maximum available area after TranslateTransform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing, rectangles

Let's say I want to draw a rectangle with an angle inside a windows form.

I can do this with

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(20);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, e.ClipRectangle.Width, e.ClipRectangle.Height);
    }
```

but this will just rotate the rectangle and thus the left and bottom part is missing.

[image: result]

But what I really want to achive is that I want to draw the biggest possible rectangle with a certain angle inside my form like this

[image: what I want to achive]

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find the rectangle at angle θ which touches all four sides. If we let W, H be the width and height of our window, th the angle in radians which are all known beforehand. Now let a, b be the width and height of the rectangle we are trying to fit in the box, these are the two values we wish to find. Let x0,y0 be the coordinates of the point in the center of the window x0=W/2, y0=H/2. One of the corners of the rectangle will be

```
x1 = x0 - 0.5 * a * sin(th) + 0.5 * b * cos(th)
y1 = y0 + 0.5 * a * cos(th) + 0.5 * b * sin(th)
```

the other point are similar with different signs. A bit of trigonometry will show this.

For the rectangle to touch the sides we want

```
a * sin(th) + b cos(th) = W
a * cos(th) + b sin(th) = H
```

this gives us a pair of simultaneous equations which we can solve. Multiply the first by sin(th) and the second by cos(th)

```
a * sin(th) sin(th) + b cos(th) sin(th) = W sin(th)
a * cos(th) cos(th) + b sin(th) cos(th) = H cos(th)
```

subtract

```
a ( sin(th) sin(th) - cos(th) cos(th) ) = W sin(th) - H cos(th)
```

divide by ( sin(th) sin(th) - cos(th) cos(th) ) gives

```
a = (W sin(th) - H cos(th)) / ( sin(th) sin(th) - cos(th) cos(th) )
```

A similar process gives

```
b = (H sin(th) - W cos(th)) / ( sin(th) sin(th) - cos(th) cos(th) )
```

Once we have the a and b we can calculate the corners of the rectangles and draw it.

I've put the code in a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SalixAlba/5jcT7/ the code is

```
// canvas and mousedown related variables
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var $canvas = $("#canvas");
var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX = $canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY = $canvas.scrollTop();
// save canvas size to vars b/ they're used often
var W = canvas.width;
var H = canvas.height;

 var spinner = $( "#startAng" ).spinner({ 
  spin: function( event, ui ) {
    if ( ui.value > 180 ) {
      $( this ).spinner( "value", ui.value - 360 );
        draw();
      return false;
    } else if ( ui.value < -180 ) {
      $( this ).spinner( "value", ui.value + 360 );
        draw();
      return false;
    }
    draw();
  }
});


var angle = 10.0;

function draw() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
angle = $("#startAng").spinner("value");
var th = Math.PI*angle/180.0;
var S = Math.sin(th);
var C = Math.cos(th);
var S2 = S*S - C*C;
var a = (W*S-H*C)/S2;
var b = (H*S-W*C)/S2;
var x0 = W/2;
var y0 = H/2;
//alert("angle "+angle+"S "+S+" "+C+" "+a+" "+b);
var x1 = x0 - 0.5 * a * Math.sin(th) + 0.5 * b * Math.cos(th);
var y1 = y0 + 0.5 * a * Math.cos(th) + 0.5 * b * Math.sin(th);

var x2 = x0 - 0.5 * a * Math.sin(th) - 0.5 * b * Math.cos(th);
var y2 = y0 + 0.5 * a * Math.cos(th) - 0.5 * b * Math.sin(th);

var x3 = x0 + 0.5 * a * Math.sin(th) + 0.5 * b * Math.cos(th);
var y3 = y0 - 0.5 * a * Math.cos(th) + 0.5 * b * Math.sin(th);

var x4 = x0 + 0.5 * a * Math.sin(th) - 0.5 * b * Math.cos(th);
var y4 = y0 - 0.5 * a * Math.cos(th) - 0.5 * b * Math.sin(th);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
ctx.lineTo(x4,y4);
ctx.lineTo(x3,y3);
ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
}

$( ".ui-spinner-input" ).on( "spinchange", draw );
$( ".ui-spinner-input" ).on( "spinstop", draw );
$( "#baseRad" ).on( "spin", draw );

draw();
```

Note this does not necessarily give the largest rectangle as there may be larger one which touch two sides, also there is some limit on the possible angle.

Answer (score -1):

I did some sketching to solve this problem. The problem is more about math than programming, but here's my idea. I did in paint but try to follow:

[image]

When you rotate the rectangle, you need to calculate the `newWidth` and `newHeight` for it. Make a new rectangle with those dimensions, and place it to the upper left corner, like your current rectangle. The alpha `α` stands for the degree you want to rotate. After rotating, you need to move this new rectangle to right, the amounth of `X`. Then you have the biggest possible rectangle positioned perfectly at your drawing area.

Here's some idea for the code. I haven't tested it:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        double angle = 20;

        double width = Convert.ToDouble(e.ClipRectangle.Width),
               height = Convert.ToDouble(e.ClipRectangle.Height),
               h = Math.Sqrt((width*width) + (height*height)),
               y = (width/h);

        int newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(height*y),
            newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(width*y),
            x = Convert.ToInt32((Math.Sin(angle) * height);

        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, x, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    }
```